# Gatsby/webpack - WebpackError window is not defined - where?

Tags: webpack, gatsby

When running gatsby build, I get the following error.

I know how to fix it (e.g. check typedef of window) but I cannot find that window usage? How can I know where is it ? I suspect a node module since I do not have many window references in my own code

Thanks a lot

```
failed Building static HTML for pages - 10.845s

 ERROR #95312 

"window" is not available during server side rendering.

See our docs page for more info on this error: https://gatsby.dev/debug-html





  WebpackError: ReferenceError: window is not defined
  
  - build-html.js:110 doBuildPages
    /[gatsby]/dist/commands/build-html.js:110:24
  
  - build-html.js:124 async buildHTML
    /[gatsby]/dist/commands/build-html.js:124:3
  
  - build.js:206 async build
    /[gatsby]/dist/commands/build.js:206:5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for all the other answers

I tried @Raz Ronen's answer but changing the globalObject made other issues like undefined localStorage.

I tried removing all the node modules but it didn't help.

Oddly, after removing the node modules the error changed and I could see the line! of the error. It was in Gatsby's own "navigate" method.

I have private routes in my app similar to what explained [in the docs](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/tutorial/authentication-tutorial/):

```
mport React from "react"
import { navigate } from "gatsby"
import { isLoggedIn } from "../services/auth"

const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, location, ...rest }) => {
  if (!isLoggedIn() && location.pathname !== `/app/login`) {
    navigate("/app/login")
    return null
  }

  return <Component {...rest} />
}

export default PrivateRoute
```

But, I had to put the navigate inside a useEffect hook in order to resolve the issue like this:

```
const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, location, ...rest }) => {
  const user = useContext(AuthenticationContext)
  useEffect(() => {
    checkLoginStatus()
  }, [])

  const checkLoginStatus = () => {
    if (!user && location.pathname !== `/login`) {
      navigate("/login")
    }
  }

  return <Component {...rest} />
}
```

Comment: You could try leaving Gatsby out of the programatic navigation (it does extra things) here. Try using the `@reach/router` `useNavigate` method. It should be passed in as a prop called `navigate` but to be sure just import it: `import { useNavigate } from "@reach/router"`

Answer (score 2):

Remove your third party node packages one at a time to find the offending module. Then you will either need to fork that package and fix it so it doesnt use the `window` object or find an alternative package.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe setting [globalObject](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#outputglobalobject) will help.

```
output: {
    globalObject: "this",
  }
```

The default of the globalObject is `window`.

Answer (score 1):

As you said, if you are not using `window` in your code (the way to fix is checking if it's defined using `typeof`), the issue comes from one of your third-party dependencies that is using the `window` as a global object in their own code.

You have to find which one is and add a `null` loader in your webpack configuration. In your `gatsby-node.js`:

```
exports.onCreateWebpackConfig = ({ stage, loaders, actions }) => {
  if (stage === "build-html") {
    actions.setWebpackConfig({
      module: {
        rules: [
          {
            test: /bad-module/,
            use: loaders.null(),
          },
        ],
      },
    })
  }
}
```

In the code above, `/bad-module/` is the dependency in `node_modules` that you want to avoid to transpile. Basically,  you are replacing the offending module with a dummy module during server rendering.