# Gatsby Unhandled Runtime Error is stating that process is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack, gatsby

It seems a very similar question to this has been asked in the following posts on StackOverflow: [firstly here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63284342/gatsby-webpack-webpackerror-window-is-not-defined-where) and [secondly here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63381461/webpackerror-referenceerror-window-is-not-defined-on-gatsby) and [thirdly here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69401258/gatsby-unhandled-runtime-error-is-stating-that-process-is-not-defined) I have followed those recommendations and have updated my devDependencies with process and have added updated my gatsby-node.js file in my root directory with the following code that was recommended:

```
exports.modifyBabelrc = ({ babelrc }) => ({
  ...babelrc,
  plugins: babelrc.plugins.concat(['transform-regenerator']),
})

exports.onCreateWebpackConfig = ({ stage, loaders, actions }) => {
  if (stage === 'build-html') {
    actions.setWebpackConfig({
      module: {
        rules: [{ test: /react-spring-3d-carousel/, use: loaders.null() }],
      },
      plugins: [
        // fix "process is not defined" error:
        // (do "npm install process" before running the build)
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
          process: 'process/browser',
        }),
      ],
    })
  }
}
```

This is the error from gatsby on the browser itslef:
[image]

This is the error my console shows:
[image]

Here is the code in my OrderDetails.js file that is bringing up this error:

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react'
import clsx from 'clsx'
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid'
import Chip from '@material-ui/core/Chip'
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button'
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography'
import SwipeableDrawer from '@material-ui/core/SwipeableDrawer'
import useMediaQuery from '@material-ui/core/useMediaQuery'
import Hidden from '@material-ui/core/Hidden'
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles'
import OrderDetailItem from './OrderDetailItem'

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  drawer: {
    height: '100%',
    width: '30rem',
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    [theme.breakpoints.down('xs')]: {
      width: '100%',
    },
  },
  id: {
    fontSize: '2.5rem',
    fontWeight: 600,
    marginTop: '1rem',
    marginLeft: '1rem',
  },
  bold: {
    fontWeight: 600,
  },
  date: {
    fontWeight: 600,
    marginLeft: '1rem',
    marginBottom: '1rem',
  },
  padding: {
    padding: '1rem',
  },
  status: {
    marginLeft: '1rem',
  },
  dark: {
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.secondary.main,
  },
  light: {
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.primary.main,
  },
  prices: {
    padding: '0.5rem 1rem',
  },
  text: {
    [theme.breakpoints.down('xs')]: {
      fontSize: '1.25rem',
    },
  },
  spacer: {
    minHeight: '10rem',
  },
}))

export default function OrderDetails({ orders, open, setOpen }) {
  const classes = useStyles()
  const matchesXS = useMediaQuery(theme => theme.breakpoints.down('xs'))

  const iOS = process.browser && /iPad|iPhone|iPod/.test(navigator.userAgent)

  const order = orders.find(order => order.id === open)

  const prices = [
    { label: 'Subtotal', value: order?.subtotal },
    { label: 'Shipping', value: order?.shippingOption.price },
    { label: 'Tax', value: order?.tax },
    { label: 'Total', value: order?.total },
    {
      label: 'Payment',
      string: `${order?.paymentMethod.brand.toUpperCase()} ${
        order?.paymentMethod.last4
      }`,
    },
    { label: 'Transaction', string: order?.transaction },
  ]

  return (
    <SwipeableDrawer
      open={!!open}
      onOpen={() => null}
      onClose={() => setOpen(null)}
      anchor={matchesXS ? 'bottom' : 'right'}
      classes={{ paper: classes.drawer }}
      disableBackdropTransition={!iOS}
      disableDiscovery={iOS}
    >
      <Hidden smUp>
        <Grid
          item
          classes={{ root: classes.spacer }}
          component={Button}
          disableRipple
          onClick={() => setOpen(null)}
        />
      </Hidden>
      <Grid container direction="column" classes={{ root: classes.light }}>
        <Grid item classes={{ root: classes.dark }}>
          <Typography variant="h2" classes={{ root: classes.id }}>
            Order #
            {order?.id
              .slice(order.id.length - 10, order.id.length)
              .toUpperCase()}
          </Typography>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item container classes={{ root: classes.dark }}>
          <Grid item classes={{ root: classes.status }}>
            <Chip
              label={order?.status}
              classes={{ label: classes.bold, root: classes.light }}
            />
          </Grid>
          <Grid item>
            <Typography variant="body2" classes={{ root: classes.date }}>
              {`${order?.createdAt.split('-')[1]}/${
                order?.createdAt.split('-')[2].split('T')[0]
              }/${order?.createdAt.split('-')[0]}`}
            </Typography>
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item classes={{ root: classes.padding }}>
          <Typography variant="body2" classes={{ root: classes.bold }}>
            Billing
          </Typography>
          <Typography variant="body2" classes={{ root: classes.text }}>
            {order?.billingInfo.name}
            <br />
            {order?.billingInfo.email}
            <br />
            {order?.billingInfo.phone}
            <br />
            <br />
            {order?.billingAddress.street}
            <br />
            {order?.billingAddress.city}, {order?.billingAddress.state}{' '}
            {order?.billingAddress.zip}
          </Typography>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item classes={{ root: clsx(classes.dark, classes.padding) }}>
          <Typography variant="body2" classes={{ root: classes.bold }}>
            Shipping
          </Typography>
          <Typography variant="body2" classes={{ root: classes.text }}>
            {order?.shippingInfo.name}
            <br />
            {order?.shippingInfo.email}
            <br />
            {order?.shippingInfo.phone}
            <br />
            <br />
            {order?.shippingAddress.street}
            <br />
            {order?.shippingAddress.city}, {order?.shippingAddress.state}{' '}
            {order?.shippingAddress.zip}
          </Typography>
        </Grid>
        {prices.map(price => (
          <Grid
            key={price.label}
            item
            container
            justifyContent="space-between"
            classes={{ root: classes.prices }}
          >
            <Grid item>
              <Typography variant="body2" classes={{ root: classes.bold }}>
                {price.label}
              </Typography>
            </Grid>
            <Grid item>
              {price.string ? (
                <Typography variant="body2" classes={{ root: classes.text }}>
                  {price.string}
                </Typography>
              ) : (
                <Chip
                  label={`$${price.value?.toFixed(2)}`}
                  classes={{ label: classes.bold }}
                />
              )}
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
        ))}
        <Grid item classes={{ root: clsx(classes.dark, classes.padding) }}>
          <Typography
            variant="body2"
            gutterBottom
            classes={{ root: classes.bold }}
          >
            Items
          </Typography>
          {order?.items.map(item => (
            <OrderDetailItem item={item} key={item.variant.id} />
          ))}
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </SwipeableDrawer>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Gatsby ships with his own version and implementation of webpack. To override/mutate it you have available the [`onCreateWebpackConfig` API (from `gatsby-node.js`)](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/config-files/gatsby-node/). You can also find an implementation example in [Adding a Custom webpack Config](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/custom-configuration/add-custom-webpack-config/).

Basically, you will need to add something like (prior to getting rid of your `webpack.config.js`):

```
exports.onCreateWebpackConfig = ({
  stage,
  plugins,
}) => {
  actions.setWebpackConfig({
    plugins: [
      new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
             process: 'process/browser',
      }),
    ],
  })
}
```

Depending on how you are importing webpack and its providers, you may need to add directly `new ProvidePlugin`.

Comment: Yes, thank you for clarifying, I have actually updated my question to include that! @FerranBuireu

Comment: `process.browser` is deprecated. Try using `window` instead (Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49411796/how-do-i-detect-whether-i-am-on-server-on-client-in-next-js) of course, wrapping it with the (`typeof window !== 'undefined'`

Comment: @FerranBuireu could you please provide an example of what you described?

Comment: There's no much secrecy, you only need to replace `process.browser` for `typeof window!== 'undefined'` in the given snippet